# Verify if there are conflicts between 2 outlook meeting using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm currently working on a macro for outlook, to create meetings from a specific date.

My macro can create, modify, delete meetings.

I would like to check if there are conflicts between meetings when I create one.

I've tried to use AppointmentItem.Conflicts property, but I couldn't have any good results.

Thank you for your help.

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Recipient.FreeBusy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.freebusy) method which returns free/busy information for the recipient. This following VBA example returns a string of free/busy information with one character for each hour (complete format).

```
Set myRecipient = myNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Nate Sun") 
myFBInfo = myRecipient.FreeBusy(#02/05/2022#, 60, True)
```

To get information for the current user you may use the [NameSpace.CurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.currentuser) property which returns the currently logged-on user as a [Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object, so may call the `FreeBusy` method on it.

Note, in case of Exchange accounts you may find the [ExchangeUser.GetFreeBusy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getfreebusy) method helpful. It returns a string representing the availability of the `ExchangeUser` for a period of 30 days from the start date, beginning at midnight of the date specified.

```
Sub GetManagerOpenInterval() 
 Dim oManager As ExchangeUser 
 Dim oCurrentUser As ExchangeUser 
 Dim FreeBusy As String 
 Dim BusySlot As Long 
 Dim DateBusySlot As Date 
 Dim i As Long 
 Const SlotLength = 60 
 'Get ExchangeUser for CurrentUser 
 If Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Type = "EX" Then 
 Set oCurrentUser = _ 
 Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser 
 'Get Manager 
 Set oManager = oManager.GetExchangeUserManager 
 If oManager Is Nothing Then 
 Exit Sub 
 End If 
 FreeBusy = oManager.GetFreeBusy(Now, SlotLength) 
 For i = 1 To Len(FreeBusy) 
 If CLng(Mid(FreeBusy, i, 1)) = 0 Then 
 'get the number of minutes into the day for free interval 
 BusySlot = (i - 1) * SlotLength 
 'get an actual date/time 
 DateBusySlot = DateAdd("n", BusySlot, Date) 
 'To refine this function, substitute actual 
 'workdays and working hours in date/time comparison 
 If TimeValue(DateBusySlot) >= TimeValue(#8:00:00 AM#) And _ 
 TimeValue(DateBusySlot) <= TimeValue(#5:00:00 PM#) And _ 
 Not (Weekday(DateBusySlot) = vbSaturday Or _ 
 Weekday(DateBusySlot) = vbSunday) Then 
 Debug.Print oManager.name & " first open interval:" & _ 
 vbCrLf & _ 
 Format$(DateBusySlot, "dddd, mmm d yyyy hh:mm AMPM") 
 Exit For 
 End If 
 End If 
 Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Also you may try to get all meeting that starts or ends in a specific interval. The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` method can help with such tasks. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)